# Brown flecks on Monstera Deliciosa

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, diseases, fungus, monstera

I just received a *Monstera deliciosa* in the post today and noticed what look like brown flecks all over the leaves.

[image]

Anybody know what they are? If it's rust, any advice on how I can treat it? It appears to have spread to all of the leaves on the plant.

I live in the UK, so am not sure what fungicides would be available (if one would be applicable here).

Answer (score 1):

The first action is to take a cotton swab with warm water, wipe gently and carefully to see if the marks are purely on the surface of the leaf. The marks look like they are spaced out in an orderly manner which kind of indicates a spraying with water containing iron in suspension which has simply dried in place.

The second action is [to review a previous post in these forums](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/monstera-deliciosa-plant-with-brown-crud-on-the-leaves) where you can see some suggestions, but note carefully the difference between the spots in that case and those in your illustration.